# How can i get the utm variables on the launch of main activity in android while referred from any marketing site?

Tags: android

How can I get the UTM variables on the launch of main activity in android while referred from any marketing site?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the main idea, but your activity has intent, that started the activity. So if it was started from url you can call `getIntent().getData()`to get the Uri.
After that you can find out all the params in that uri because Uri class has a lot of helper methods, for example getQuery.